# How to use Prisma Enum in Nest JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am using prisma with nestjs for my backend. I have written enum in prisma which is working correctly in debug mode. but when i generate prisma client along with `nest build`, I am getting error.

```js
Object.values(client_1.RoomSharingType).join(', '),
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

the DTO, I am defining is:-

```
import {
  RoomSharingType,
} from '@prisma/client';

export class ValidationDemo {
  @IsEnum(RoomSharingType, {
    message:
      'OTP Type must be one of these values: ' +
      Object.values(RoomSharingType).join(', '),
  })
  @IsString()
  type: RoomSharingType;
}
```

Prisma Schema

```
enum RoomSharingType {
  TYPE1
  TYPE2
}
```

[image: import]

Everything is working in debug mode, but whenever i run build, i am getting the above error message.

The type generated by prisma client should work on nestjs end in production build file.

Comment: Are you importing the type instead of the value? Please send the full code.

Comment: Hi, i've updated the question. I don't think I am importing the types only

Comment: That's weird, what build tool are you using?

Because if you go to [this Prisma playground](https://playground.prisma.io/examples/reading/find/find-all?host=playground.prisma.io&path=examples) and run:

`import { Role } from "@prisma/client"; console.log(Object.values(Role));`

It would work.

Comment: yes, it was my fault, i have to copy prisma directory from my docker file and run `prisma generate`. I thought the build file contains generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the issue, i need to copy the `prisma` directory too and run `prisma generate`. I thought the build file contains all generated code.